# Define template to be used in a Loc in sitemap

Tags: scala, lift

Using the Sitemap, one can set certain paths to work on prefix matching, and allow requests for subpaths to be served. I'd like to specify that all requests below the given path go to a certain template. So I would like:

```
Menu(Loc("show_theme", Link("show" :: "theme" :: Nil, true, "/show/theme"), "Show Theme") )
```

to catch all requests to /show/theme/* (which it does), but serve them using the template at /show/theme (which it doesn't)

I want (e.g.) /show/theme/1 to use the template at /show/theme, and the snippets within that to pull the id out of the Req.

Is this possible? Or am I doing things the wrong way? At the moment, I'm using /show_theme?theme=1, but this is a bit ugly, and makes working with forms difficult

EDIT: I'm trying to get away from using CGI params to encode IDs, and keep them as part of the path structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Loc represents one page and one template.  If you want to map multiple URLs to the Loc than you'll want to use Lift's URL rewriting.  For example:

```
LiftRules.statefulRewrite.append {

  case RewriteRequest(ParsePath("show" :: "theme" :: theme :: Nil, _, _, _), _, _) =>
    RewriteResponse(ParsePath("show_theme" :: Nil, "", true, false), Map("theme" -> theme), false)

}
```

What that will do is match requests to /show/theme/* and rewrite them to /show_theme?theme={theme}.  You them create your Loc to respond to that URL and you access the theme variable as a query parameter (S.param("theme")).

Note: You can do this more concisely by using the Loc DSL but I think it's good to understand what is going on behind the scenes.

If you need more help I would suggest you post a message to the [Lift Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb).  I think you'll find quicker answers there than you will on SO.

Comment: OK, that's helpful, but it doesn't quite do what I want - I've tried to clarify the question. I'm not sure that a Loc always represents one page/template, though - with prefix matching, it can be any number of pages/templates. I'd like to turn that into any number of pages, with a single template, but avoid CGI params.

Comment: The example code I provided doesn't require the URL to actually contain any query parameters, it rewrites the portion of /show/theme/{theme} in brackets so that it appears to be a query parameter as far as your snippets are concerned.

Comment: Ooops, my misunderstanding - I (foolishly) assumed it would cause a redirect, but of course that's not the case. I had to put a Nil on the end of the first list ("show"::"theme"::theme::Nil) but it works perfectly, thank you!